# Process Excel file with headings and data blocks in Python without loop

Tags: python

I receive an Excel sheet with a layout like this (which I can't change as I just receive it):

| Category A |
| Article Name | Quantity |
| Article 1 | 100 |
| Article 2 | 75 |
|  |  |
| Category B |
| Article Name | Quantity |
| Article 3 | 10 |
| Article 4 | 175 |
|  |  |

And I need to transform this in a format where the category information is added to each line and empty rows are skipped

Target format is a dataframe/table/??? like this:

| Article Name | Quantity | Category |
| Article 1 | 100 | Category A |
| Article 2 | 75 | Category A |
| Article 3 | 10 | Category B |
| Article 4 | 175 | Category B |

Currently I loop over the Excel and whenever I see category info by checking for the four category values (".... in ('Category A', ' Category B'.....)") I start a new block and take the following rows until I see a blank row.

Is there a more elegant way to do that without looping over all rows? The loop works but doesn't feel very efficient/elegant at all....Therefore any hints are highly appreciated to improve!

I use the loop and it works but I'd like to learn a more efficient approach if somebody can give me a hint

Comment: could you include an example of your current code, in a code block?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.